# Is Oracle's SYS_GUID() UUID RFC 4122 compliant?

Tags: oracle, uuid, rfc

I wonder if Oracle's SYS_GUID() function returns [a RFC 4122 compliant UUID](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). For example:

```
SQL> select sys_guid() from dual;

SYS_GUID()
--------------------------------
A6C1BD5167C366C6E04400144FD25BA0
```

I know, that SYS_GUID() returns a 16 byte RAW datatype. Oracle uses RAWTOHEX() and probably TO_CHAR() to print out the above ID. Is it correct to interpret this as a UUID compliant string format like:

```
A6C1BD51-67C3-66C6-E044-00144FD25BA0
```

I think it's not compliant to the RFC 4122 standard, because the definition says, that a valid UUID must name the UUID-Version within the UUID itself.

Syntax for a RFC 4122 compliant UUID (Version 3):

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-3xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The SYS_GUID returns a RAW datatype. The client (eg sqlplus) is rendering that into a readable format.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SYS_GUID is Oracle's *equivalent* of UUID.  It is globally unique.  However, it is not compliant to RFC 4122; I'm inferring lack of compliance from the absence of references to UUID in the documentation (outside the Java XML documentation).

I suspect Oracle haven't natively implemented RFC 4122 because they don't think it scales.  I can't imagine why else they would invent their own thing instead of complying to a standard.

Answer (score 29):

If you want that format try this:

```
select regexp_replace(rawtohex(sys_guid())
       , '([A-F0-9]{8})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{12})'
       , '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') 
         as FORMATTED_GUID 
 from dual
```

**Example Results:**

```
 FORMATTED_GUID                                                                  
 ------------------------------------
 F680233E-0FDD-00C4-E043-0A4059C654C9
```

Comment: For a bulk data processing to get a bit better performance by avoiding REGEXP see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354555/formating-string-without-regexp-replace-and-pl-sql)

Comment: Thats not returning an valid version 3 UUID because it should have the format xxxxxxxx-xxxx-3xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (version 3) or xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (version 4)

Answer (score 4):

With sufficient privileges, it is possible to have Oracle generate compliant UUIDs.

**1. By defining a SQL function**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956771, you can do the following:

```sql
create or replace function random_uuid return RAW is
  v_uuid RAW(16);
begin
  v_uuid := sys.dbms_crypto.randombytes(16);
  return (utl_raw.overlay(utl_raw.bit_or(utl_raw.bit_and(utl_raw.substr(v_uuid, 7, 1), '0F'), '40'), v_uuid, 7));
end random_uuid;
```

The function requires `dbms_crypto` and `utl_raw`. Both require an execute grant.

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to uuid_user;
```

**2. Using a Java procedure**

To create a Java procedure for creating a compliant UUID, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951615.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 4122 § 3.  Namespace Registration Template (Page 5)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#page-5)

> Validation mechanism:
> Apart from determining whether the timestamp portion of the UUID
> is in the future and therefore not yet assignable, there is no
> mechanism for determining whether a UUID is 'valid'.

It is the generation process that determines "compliance" with RFC 4122, the **UUID** itself is just a 128 bit **ID**entifier.

Therefore the answer is yes, why would it not be compliant?  A **UUID** is just an 128 bit **U**niversaly **U**nique **ID**entifier, the rest of the spec is just recommended ways to help you/Oracle generate identifiers that do not collide with other systems that generate **U.U. ID**entifiers.  If you or Oracle do not want to follow their recommendations, they are free to do so.  Regardless, the uuid you gave is "in compliance" with RFC 4122 as the variant field starts with the bit sequence `111` which is "Reserved for future definition.".  The spec was written in the past and does not restrict who can specify a "future definition", it certainly does not prevent Oracle from defining their own variants... therefore it is "in compliance"... lol.

p.s. I love how the original authors anticipated your question and added sarcasm quotes around 'valid'.