# Add temp column with default as trim of an existing column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, trim, alter

I am trying to add a temporary column to a table in order to fix leading and trailing spaces in the original column.

Original Column values (excluding speech marks):

```
" John Smith   "
"  Jay Morgan  "
```

Temporary column values (excluding speech marks):

```
"John Smith"
"Jay Morgan"
```

SQL:

```
alter table persons
add t_full_name as default trim(full_name);
```

However, this does not work. Am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: What about this column makes it "temporary"?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is temporary because it needs to exist for a while getting its value from the original column as trimmed until I  drop the original column and rename the temp column to original.

Comment: Did you search how to add a column? Where do you define the datatype, for example.

Comment: Yes, I know the syntax ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype; I tried using VARCHAR2(255) instead of as - did not work either.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just update the existing column values - performance? Can new rows be added after you add this new column? And are you adding a constraint on the new column to prevent leading/trailing spaces in future? It might be simpler to add a (permanent) virtual column and leave the padded column alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (Oracle 11g):

```
CREATE TABLE T2 (full_name VARCHAR2(40));
INSERT INTO T2 (full_name) VALUES ('  test  ');
SELECT * FROM T2;
ALTER TABLE T2 ADD (fu2 VARCHAR2(40) as (TRIM(full_name)));
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

Output

```
FULL_NAME   FU2
  test      test
```

Added after comment.
If later you want to rename columns as you told, you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE T2 ADD fu3 VARCHAR2(40);
UPDATE T2 SET fu3=fu2;
ALTER TABLE T2 DROP COLUMN fu2;
ALTER TABLE T2 DROP COLUMN full_name;
ALTER TABLE T2 RENAME COLUMN fu3 TO full_name;
```

Or directly, if you don't want to do intermediate checks:

```
UPDATE T2 SET full_name=fu2;
ALTER TABLE T2 DROP COLUMN fu2;
```

Comment: This works, but it creates the temp column as a virtual column which will not allow me to rename/drop the original column as it used in the fu2 expression.

Comment: @Singh I added something to answer (I hope I understood your needs)

Comment: Yes, I saw it but there are too many operations happening now. I have solved the issue now using a procedure and updating all VARCHAR2 columns to trimmed version of the original column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trigger instead of a function in the default value.
Here an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setTrimValue BEFORE INSERT ON persons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.t_full_name := TRIM(:OLD.full_name)
END;
```

Please check here: [Use function as default value for column in Oracle11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795654/use-function-as-default-value-for-column-in-oracle11g)

> Restriction on Default Column Values
>   A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date constants that are not fully specified.

[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7002.htm#i2128561)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet of/link to the documentation, it really helps.

Comment: You can use `trim()` as that's a built-in function, not a PL/SQL function. But you can't refer to the `full_name` column, as the doc link also says. A trigger won't set the value for existing rows though.

Comment: Hmm. I need the existing rows to be fixed as well. Anyways I have solved the issue now by actually updating the original column to trim(original_column).

Answer (score 1):

Add a [virtual column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2183462):

```
ALTER TABLE PERSONS
ADD t_full_name GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TRIM( BOTH FROM full_name ) );
```

Comment: I cannot use virtual column as it causes issues later when renaming the original column.