# I am getting an error trying to create a table in sql (ORA-04044)

Tags: sql, oracle

[Im not too sure how I can fix this. Some help would be much appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVqiv.png)

I tried moving some of the constraints around and nothing seemed to work. I'm unable to find anything online to help me. Ive tried removing things and renaming but nothing seems to work.

Adding code from attached screenshot (Jeff)

```
create table users_sys(
    userid int primary key,
    username varchar2(255) unique not null,
    email varchar2(255) unique not null,
    registrationdate date default getdate() not null)
);
```

And error -

```
Error report -ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here04044. 00000 -  "procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here"
*Cause:    A procedure, function, or package was specified in an
```

Comment: Can you please show us where you got this syntax:  `userid int primary key`?

Comment: Also you have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Are you sure Oracle has `GETDATE()` function?

Answer (score 0):

This will give what you want -

```
create table users_sys (
    userid           int primary key,
    username         varchar2(255) unique not null,
    email            varchar2(255) unique not null,
    registrationdate date default sysdate not null
);
```

...Assuming that your getDate() function returns the current date value in your database.

[This is basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795654/use-function-as-default-value-for-column-in-oracle11g), showing how to use a trigger to use a user defined function to supply a value for your column.