# create a random uuid function and use it to generate column value in oracle

Tags: oracle, uuid

I am trying to migrate PostgreSQL to Oracle database as per client requirements.
In PostgreSQL I have used uuid data type and the values of the column are generated automatically using the uuid_generate_v4() function. I want to know the alternative in Oracle. I went through the documentation but its not clear if I can create a function and use it to generate a column value.
This post was little helpful but don't understand how to use this function in create or alter statement
[How to generate a version 4 (random) UUID on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951576/how-to-generate-a-version-4-random-uuid-on-oracle/13956771#13956771)

Comment: See Kirill's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951576/how-to-generate-a-version-4-random-uuid-on-oracle. This is what I have been using successfully for several months.

Comment: You need SQL functions rather than user-defined functions in the `DEFAULT` clause [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e39169998f6929cddffc04223fc7be99).

Comment: You can write a before-insert trigger to call a UUID function and assign the value.